# C# mysql returning list of rows

Tags: c#, .net, mysql-connector

I would like to return ArrayList of values from mysql database. I have tried couple of solutions but they were not as elegant as I need. My problem: I have a table in database that can change structure (alter table). I need a way to detect current table structure and then to put the data in array list with right types (no casting to Object) are there any solutions to this problem ? I dont want logic that is written bellow inside while.

```
IDbCommand sql = dbLink.CreateCommand ();
sql.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE cond";

IDataReader reader = null;

try 
{
    reader = sql.ExecuteReader ();
} 
catch (Exception er) 
{
    Log.error ("error executing query");
}

while(reader.Read()) 
{
    //dont want like this
    value = (string)reader["item"];
    //logic to implement
}


reader.Close ();
reader = null;
sql.Dispose ();
sql = null;
```

Comment: You should be wrapping your connections in a `using....` Also, ditch the `ArrayList`, stick to the normal `IEnumerable` or `List` unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `ArrayList` is just going to store it as `Object` anyway, you can just use:

```
list.Add(reader["item"]);
```

That just puts the onus on whatever's going to *fetch* it from the list to cast it before they can do anything useful though. Think about whatever code *is* going to consume these results, and how you're expecting it to handle them.

(I agree with Arran's comment though - you should use `using` statements. Also, you almost never want to set variables to null after you're done with them, you shouldn't catch just `Exception`, and you definitely shouldn't try to use `reader` after an exception has been thrown - you'll just end up with a `NullReferenceException`.)